# Javascript spread async generator into Array

Tags: javascript, generator

Нello, if I have a generator such as:

```
let myGen = function*() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
};
```

I use nifty shorthand to dump generator values into an Array with `[ ...myGen() ]`:

```js
let myGen = function*(){ yield 1; yield 2; yield 3; };
console.log([ ...myGen() ]);
```

My question is: is there an equivalent of this for async generators?

For example for this generator:

```
let myGen = async function*() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100));
    yield i;
  }
}
```

What is the cleanest way to dump all generator values into an Array?

Here are some attempts:

```js
let myGen = async function*() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100));
    yield i;
  }
};

let attempts = [
  async () => [ ...myGen() ],
  async () => await [ ...myGen() ],
  async () => [ ...(await myGen()) ]
];

(async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < attempts.length; i++) {
    try {
      console.log(`Attempt ${i + 1} success: ${await attempts[i]()}`);
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(`Attempt ${i + 1} failure (${err.message})`);
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: do you have a real problem to solve? or is this codereview? using setTimeout is not equivalent

Comment: I do have a real problem! I'll be able to address it more cleanly if I can dump an async generator's results into an array

Comment: `async function toArray(iter) { const arr = []; for await (const el of iter) arr.push(el); return arr; }`

Comment: @Bergi that's pretty much what I'm using at the moment! I was wondering if spread syntax is capable of the same thing. Of course it may not exist, and if not I'll use that solution.

Comment: @Gershom No. Spread syntax is for synchronous generators only. See my comment on the duplicate for an `await myGen().toArray()` solution

Comment: Yes I saw it! Thanks for providing the duplicate, I couldn't find it myself. Although I did follow your link, but it didn't seem to take me anywhere relevant (I ctrl+f'd for "toArray" on that page and found nothing)